# Django is not refreshing content without server start

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-settings

I am working on DjangoRest Framework, if I update values from the API, and see the content on the frontend, the changes are not getting reflected without server startup. For debugging, I also directly changed the value in the database, but the changes are not getting reflected either in this case too. 
What could be the reason behind this? Can someone point me out in the right direction?
I read about it and someone told this is happening because of .pyc files I even deleted them. But nothing solved my issue yet.
If you need to see any screenshot or logs. I am happy to provide it. But How can i resolve it ?

Comment: Are you able to see the updated values when you calling the APIs? (not by using your front-end application such as react, angular, etc)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes, i am able to see the updated values while calling API.